# Google sheet + App script: use showDialog box to find and replace value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm using this script to show a dialog box so I can enter a value then hit the submit button and get the script newcc(num) to inserted the value entered into the box onto another worksheet in Column 'I' where the check value from Column 'A' matches but for some reason it wont work any help would be great
here is my GS code

```
    function newcostcode(){

   showDialogCostCode()
   
   }
 

function newcc(num){
 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kiDnEawj0--- ID----NfjHQ-zeBHSvQ');
    var ws =  ss.getSheetByName('Data');
    

if (newcc(num) !== ''){
      
       var check = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Ticket PDF').getRange('N2').getValue();
      
       ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
      .createTextFinder(check)
      .findAll()
      .pop()
      .offset(0, 8, 1, 1)//column I PO AFE
      .setValue(newcc(num))
    
  }
}



function showDialogCostCode() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('updateCostCode')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(200);
       SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Update Cost Code ');
```

}

and here's part of my html code

```
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                   
                      <label for="costcode">Enter New Cost Code</label>
                      <input type="text" id="CC" class="form-control  col-md-2" >
                     
                      <br>
                      
                      <button onclick="updateCC()" class="btn btn-primary  ">Submit</button>
                      
                      <script>
                      function updateCC(){
                      var newCC = document.getElementById("CC");
                      var num = newCC.value
                      google.script.run.newcc(num);
                      }
                      </script>
                  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare the value of a function **newcc(num)** instead of the passed parameter **num** only.

### Solution

Use the passed variable **num** to replace newcc(num) in comparing values. Your ***newcc(num)*** function should look like this:

```
function newcc(num){
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1kiDnEawj0--- ID----NfjHQ-zeBHSvQ');
  var ws =  ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  
  
  if (num !== ''){
    
    var check = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Ticket PDF').getRange('N2').getValue();
    
    ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
    .createTextFinder(check)
    .findAll()
    .pop()
    .offset(0, 8, 1, 1)//column I PO AFE
    .setValue(num)
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was the issue it working good  just wondering what would need to be done so it would change every matching rows not just the last one

Comment: In your code, you're only performing 1 update. To update all matching rows, you might need to iterate/loop through all of the ranges that are returned by findAll() and perform the offset and setValue on each matching row.